# How to grep for the string if it is not followed by alphanumeric

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I need the below requirement

```
string123

stringsecond

string-third

-string-four

string_five

/string/

sixstring

this should not print
```

## output

```
string-third

-string-four

string_five

/string/
```

So as per the output,the command should not grep string followed with alphanumeric only.
I am using -w option with grep ,but it is eliminating underscore(_) strings also.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: grep -nriw "string" <file_name>            // w for match the string

Comment: -w is removing the string_five also,but I have to grep that also

Comment: Something like `grep  -v 'string[0-9a-zA-Z]' file` should solve it
`

Comment: Thanks,its working good..but it can not handle "sixstring" what I added in the question. prefixed with alphanumeric also avoided.can we do that ?

Comment: I got a problem here,your command is printing the lines not having "string" also as per the output. I have to grep for lines having the string without prefixed and suffixed with alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class at the end of your regex.

If you're matching "string", then append a class like `[^0-9a-zA-Z_]` to the end.